# Type Error when trying to save model in tensorflow python, getting trace 'Unrecognized type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>.'

Tags: json, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm relatively new to python and machine learning and I'm trying to classify chest X-ray scans and I created a model that does that. However, when I'm trying to save the model I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: Unable to serialize [2.0896919 2.1128857 2.1081853] to JSON. Unrecognized type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>.
```

The full Stack Trace is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_22092\3924096485.py in <module>
      1 working_dir=os.getcwd()
      2 subject='chest scans'
----> 3 save_model(subject, classes, img_size, f1score, working_dir)

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_22092\541087647.py in save_model(subject, classes, img_size, f1score, working_dir)
      3     save_id=f'{name}-{f1score:5.2f}.h5'
      4     model_save_loc=os.path.join(working_dir, save_id)
----> 5     model.save(model_save_loc)
      6     msg= f'model was saved as {model_save_loc}'
      7     print_in_color(msg, (0,255,255), (100,100,100)) # cyan foreground

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

~\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    232     if cls is None:
    233         cls = JSONEncoder
--> 234     return cls(
    235         skipkeys=skipkeys, ensure_ascii=ensure_ascii,
    236         check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,

~\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py in encode(self, o)
    197         # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    198         # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 199         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    200         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    201             chunks = list(chunks)

~\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py in iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    255                 self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    256                 self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 257         return _iterencode(o, 0)
    258 
    259 def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,

TypeError: Unable to serialize [2.0896919 2.1128857 2.1081853] to JSON. Unrecognized type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>.
```

I have created this function to save the model:

```
def save_model(subject, classes, img_size, f1score, working_dir):
    name=subject + '-' + str(len(classes)) + '-(' + str(img_size[0]) + ' X ' + str(img_size[1]) + ')'
    save_id=f'{name}-{f1score:5.2f}.h5'
    model_save_loc=os.path.join(working_dir, save_id)
    model.save(model_save_loc)
    msg= f'model was saved as {model_save_loc}'
    print_in_color(msg, (0,255,255), (100,100,100)) # cyan foreground
```

I have the following packages installed for tensorflow.

```
tensorboard                  2.8.0
tensorboard-data-server      0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit       1.8.1
tensorflow                   2.8.1
tensorflow-estimator         2.8.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.28.0
termcolor                    1.1.0
keras                        2.8.0
keras-nightly                2.5.0.dev2021032900
Keras-Preprocessing          1.1.2
```

Any help would be great! I am really not being able to convert the tensorflow `EagerTensor` to Json File for my ML model. Thanks!

I tried to save a ml model that I created and I failed and it's giving me an error when converting it to json file

Answer (score 2):

So I tried to downgrade tensorflow from V2.10 to V2.9.1, this function works fine. In other words, this is a bug in 2.10.0. Hope it helps and please fix this bug for V2.10

Comment: still a bug in V2.12.0 looks like. *sigh* ...

Answer (score 0):

(using TensorFlow 2.10.1)

Try checking if you are passing TF Tensors as arguments for any Keras objects that expect NumPy arrays.

I don't know if this is a universal TF/Keras issue, but I encountered this problem when instantiating an initializer for an embedding layer. If `initializer = tf.keras.initializers.Constant(c)`, `c` must be a NumPy array. If `c` is a TF Tensor, the model trains fine but generates the OP's error during serialization.